# PHP+MYSQL Server Config

Tags: mysql, simplexml, php

I am parsing an XML file with PHP and inserting the rows in a MYSQL database.

I am using PHP simplexml_load_files to load the XML and a foreach to loop through the array and insert the rows into my database.

It works perfectly fine with small files i am testing, but it comes to reality I need to parse a large 500mb XML file and nothing happens.

I was wondering what was the right Php.ini config for this case ?

I have a VPS Linux Cent OS, with 256 mb of dedicated Memory and MYSQL 5.0.5. I have also set php memory_limit = 256M (maximum of my server)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gosh, a 500 MB XML file? I guess you run out of memory. try [XMLReader](http://php.net/xmlreader), that’s a pull parser (parsing the XML (more or less) linewise), so that you don’t run out of memory so easily.

Comment: Yes, it may work but that requires rewriting my code again..  Is there any chance to use simplexml_load_file for large files ?

Comment: SimpleXML (like DOMDocument) parse the XML as a whole and have to create a DOM tree. this easily requires more than 100 times the file size in memory.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [xmlreader](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.xmlreader.php) ... its more efective as memory is concerned

Answer (score 0):

The memory config used for xml is located in a third party library, not at php.ini config.
Besides that you should XMLReader or ext/xml to process such a large file, that means streaming access and not use dom data access (SimpleXML).